# inward or outward normal to a surface?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

I've got a conceptual problem regarding inward and outward normals. The textbook question (2nd year vector calculus) is as follows:

> A uniform fluid that flows vertically downward is described by the vector field $\mathbf F(x,y,z) = -\mathbf k$. Find the flux through the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ , \ \ \ x^2+y^2\le1$

So I've parametrised the surface in cylindrical coordinates as $$\Phi(\rho,\phi) = (\rho\cos(\phi),\rho\sin(\phi),\rho)$$ with $0\le\rho\le 1$ and $0\le\phi\le2\pi$

Then
$$\vec {\mathbf T_\rho} = (\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),1)
\\ \vec {\mathbf T_\phi} = (-\rho\sin(\phi),\rho\cos(\phi),0)$$
$$\vec {\mathbf T_\rho} \ \ \times \ \ \vec {\mathbf T_\phi} =  
\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j &\mathbf k \\ 
                 \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) & 1 \\
                 -\rho\sin(\phi) & \rho\cos(\phi) & 0
    \end{vmatrix} \\ = \ (-\rho\cos(\phi), -\rho\sin(\phi), \rho)
$$

But then I try to calculate $$\iint_s \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf s \\ = \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi} (0,0,-1) \ \cdot \ (-\rho\cos(\phi), -\rho\sin(\phi), \rho) \ \mathrm d\phi \ \mathrm d\rho \\ = \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi} -\rho \ \mathrm d\phi \mathrm d\rho \\ = \int_0^1 -2\pi\rho \ \mathrm d\rho \\ = -\pi$$

which is the negative of the actual answer of $\pi$. I've got a feeling it's to do with the order of the cross product so my question is:

> How can I fix this problem, and why is it that I should take the reverse cross product?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\rho$-curve i.e. fixing some $\rho$ and vary $\phi$ is vertical translation of some circle in $XY$ plane and it's tangent is $\overrightarrow T_\phi$ which is something looks like vertical translation of some tangent to a circle of $XY$ plane.

Now for a $\phi$-curve if you increase $\rho$ then you traverse this $\phi$-curve upward direction i.e. tangent to this $\phi$-curve has direction upwards, in some sense same direction as of $\widehat k$.

Now if you apply right-handed rule to find the direction of $\overrightarrow T_\rho\ ×\ \overrightarrow T_\phi$ which direct towards OUTSIDE of the solid region inside the cone , but then $\overrightarrow T_\phi\ ×\ \overrightarrow T_\rho\ =  -\ \overrightarrow T_\rho\ ×\ \overrightarrow T_\phi$ directs towards the INSIDE of the solid region of the cone.

Therefore $\overrightarrow T_\phi\ ×\ \overrightarrow T_\rho$ is the INWARD drawn normal to the surface. And $\overrightarrow T_\rho\ ×\ \overrightarrow T_\phi$ is OUTWARD drawn normal to the surface.

Comment: cheers, this helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The normal to the cone which you are using is pointing upwards (as you can see from the positivity of the third coordinate, or by using the three finger rule applied to the tow tangent vectors), while the vector field $F$ is pointing downward. This must result in a negative value for the flow.

Comment: thanks for the help :)